# Why did Microsoft remove Ajax-baased login and registration workflows from the templates in MVC4 RC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't see the following json methods in AccountController.cs from beta software.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult JsonLogin(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult JsonRegister(RegisterModel model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because ajax concepts, like asynchronous http requests, callbacks etc., are a little advanced for beginners. Without these "complications" the MCV project template is more beginner-friendly and can receive broader acceptance. More skilled users, on the other hand, are able to figure out how to ajaxify their apps on their own. Personally, I would prefer Microsoft to provide an "Enable ajax methods" checkbox in the Create Project dialog.